# Matrix second order interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have the following matrix

```
$$\begin{bmatrix}
k_{11}(y_1)  & k_{12} (y_2)  &  \hdots & k_{1N_S} (y_{N_S})  \\
k_{21}(y_2)  & \ddots & &    \vdots     \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
k_{N_S1}(y_{N_S})   & \hdots  & \hdots & k_{N_SN_S} (y_{N_S})
\end{bmatrix}$$
```

where each element is computed at a point in a non-uniform mesh `$y_j$`, `$j=1`,`\hdots`, `N_S$`

I want to interpolate this matrix (second order) to a new mesh, say `$z_j$`, `$j=1`,`\hdots`, `N_D$`, with `$N_D<N_S$`, so that the new matrix will be

```
$$\begin{bmatrix}
k^*_{11}(z_1)  & k^*_{12} (z_2)  &  \hdots & k^*_{1N_D} (z_{N_D})  \\
k^*_{21}(z_2)  & \ddots & &    \vdots     \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
k^*_{N_S1}(z_{N_D})   & \hdots  & \hdots & k^*_{N_DN_D} (z_{N_D})
\end{bmatrix}$$
```

where `$k^*_{ij}$` are the corresponding interpolated values of `$k_{ij}$`.

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Even if the LaTeX (?) markup didn't confuse the issue I think I'd think this question is too broad hereabouts.

Comment: Is Latex supported?

Comment: @Peter No. Please put the equations